# Incorrect result when finding word in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a piece of code which finds a word in a string and shows how many times it appears, but if I enter one letter, for example 'a' it will find all occurrences of 'a' in the string, rather than just 'a' on it's own. The code I have currently is:

```
for For in SentenceSplit:
     #looks for the users word in the sentence
     if re.search(Word, str(For)):
        #if found adds one to the counter
        counter=counter+1
```

Comment: Why are you using `re.search` instead of just `userWord == userFor`?

Comment: If you are searching for a single character, then you are not testing for the character separated from other characters to make a "word" Test your code by using input of two characters as a word with the same two characters inside a string and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: to find it if it occurs more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split()` to split the string to words and `==` for comparison.

```
s = "a rat and a cat"
w = 'a'
count = 0
for useFor in s.split(' '):
    if w == useFor:
        count += 1
print count
```

outputs : `2`

Refer to C Panda's answer if you like the regex way of matching strings.

Comment: what string did you use? Can you give an example?

Comment: it's a user input string so varies each time (raw_input)

Comment: Still there you will have a case or an example where it didn't work right?

Comment: ah, i tried 'to to to tool' to see if it counted the 'to' but not the 'tool'

Comment: correction, it now works! i checked over it and had misplaced a variable!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do correctly,

```
ah a banana a fruit
```

should get split into

```
ah, a, banana, a, fruit
```

if you're looking for `a`, then `ah`, `banana`, and `fruit` should not match, while the two occurrences of `a` should. Thus the result you want is `2`.

If you're looking for a fixed string (such as `userWord = "a"`), you can find it simply as

```
counter = userSentenceSplit.count(userWord)
```

For example

```
"ah a banana a fruit".split().count("a")
```

is `2`. `count`, as you'd expect, counts the occurrences of some element in a list. (In strings, it counts occurrences of substrings, which might have confused you.)

If your search pattern is more complex and you truly need regexps, you can replace `re.search` with [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match), which matches only at the beginning of the search string.

If your search pattern contains an end (e.g. you don't want `a` to match `ah`), make sure to end the pattern in `$`.

```
>>> re.match("a", "a")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
>>> re.match("a", "a longer string")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
>>> re.match("a$", "a")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='a'>
>>> re.match("a$", "a longer string") # No match
None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open('filename','r').read()##file with the sentences
f1=f.split('\n')
l=[]
for i in range (len(f1)):
    a=f1[i].split(' ')
    for wd in a:
        l.append(wd)
c=0
word=raw_input('enter the word:')
for el in l:
    if word==l[el]:
       c+=1
if c==0:
    print 'word not found'
else:
    print 'word found, no of times=',c
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

```
reg = r"\b{}\b".format(word)
matches = re.findall(reg, sentence)
len(matches)
```

Comment: This will have the same issue as the current approach (`"a rat".count("a")` returns 2, not 1 as desired

Comment: this counts all occurences of `word` in the long string sentence even if it is buried within another string. `efghijk` will have `ghi` found even though it is a substring and not a "word"